# Append the code right after the current index

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an *add* button that allows repeating the code.

```html
  <div *ngFor="let detail of _detailRowNumber">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Label of a detail</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Description of a detail</mat-label>
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button *ngIf="_detailRowNumber.length > 1" (click)="decreaseDetailRow(detail)" mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="Add a new row for a new detail">
      <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <button (click)="increaseDetailRow()" mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="Add a new row for a new detail">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
```

```js
_detailRowNumber: Array<number> = [0];

increaseDetailRow(): void {
  this._detailRowNumber.push((this._detailRowNumber.length - 1) + 1);
}
```

Let's say the code will loop 10 times. My problem is that it appends the code always at the last position, no matter what *add* button I am clicking on. What I want is to append the code right after the section of the button that has been clicked. How can I do this?

I have also tried it with the following method but I see no difference:

```js
increaseDetailRow(index: number): void {
  this._detailRowNumber.splice(index, 0, index++);
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding `1` and subtracting `1`: `(this._detailRowNumber.length - 1) + 1`?

Comment: Can you try with get index of selected button and use the shift function?

Comment: Could you wrap the form fields and buttons in another div? And try. I mean a div inside the "for-loop" div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal for your code to be appended at the last position, since that's what `push` does to an array. If you want to insert it in a specific position you're correct to try the `splice` of the array and pass the value of the index from the `ngFor`. That should work, e.g.:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.splice(1, 0, 3);
console.log(test); - [1, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here's a quick example on stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oycdbk?file=src/app/app.component.html. You can see how when you click `add` button, at the specific position the element with a value `index + 1` is successfully added at that position/index, so I think that your `splice` logic might also work but that you're looking at it wrong, since there's not a lot of difference that you can see when you're rendering the same elements with mocked data.